# Twitter Bootstrap rendering HTML instead of space

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap, with my ASP.Net MVC project.

I'm using an EditorTemplate, which should add two classes to the input box:

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime> 

@if ( Model.HasValue ) { 
   @Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" , Model.Value ) , new  { @class = "span3 disabled" } ) 
} 
else { 
   @Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" , DateTime.Now ) , new     { @class = "span3 disabled" } ) 
}
```

Where I have:

```
new  { @class = "span3 disabled" }
```

in the Editor Template, this is rendered with `&#32;` instead of the space - which then doesn't pick up the class from CSS:

```
class="span3&#32;disabled"
```

Can this be rendered as:

```
class="span3 disabled"
```

I've tried adding `@class = @Html.Raw("span3 disabled")` to the EditorTemplate, but it still shows with the `&#32`; instead of the space in the markup.

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: This probably won't work, but can you try changing `Html.Raw()` to `new HtmlString("...")`?

Comment: Hi  - thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work - it says HtmlString is a type, and is being used like a variable.

Comment: That's bizarre; did you preface it with `new`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload which takes IDictionary for htmlattributes, helps specially for attributes like, 'data-role-id' and such. Following might help

```
@Html.TextBox("dateandtime", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now), new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "span3 disabled" } })
```

Comment: Hi - thank you - that unfortunately also rendered: span3&#32;disabled

Comment: Ahh - so it's currently "by design" - that throws a spanner in the works a little!!  Thank you for trying to help.